# EXC_BAD_EXCESS with sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all message on console

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, shared-libraries, exc-bad-access

I m trying to put two different view on one xib. out of  which in one view I m using two table view.I did all IBOutlet and mapping part perfectly.
And while loading it ,I get this message (which is shown in image).
And when I hide the `self.table1.delegate=self; 
                    self.table2.delegate=self;
                    self.table1.datasource=self; 
                    self.table2.datasource=self;`

its shows normal view whatever I want, but both the tables without data n scroll.
I m using XCODE 4.2 IDE and lion os.

Comment: as I m new user it dosent allow me to upload image..

Comment: message is EXC_BAD_EXCESS in thread 1;

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_EXCESS errors are caused by over released objects (which aren't set to nil). To track these down you use zombies. While there are multiple ways of using zombies, I prefer....

"Profile" your code to run it using Instruments. Choose the 'Zombies' instrument. Re-create the error. Instruments will pause, point to the memory location and give you a list of all the places the zombie was retained and released as well as providing a call tree to show where it happens in your code.

Comment: It gives this tipe of message=
, *** -[chapterViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6862c10
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all,

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to access something with was possibly auto-released in the `chapterViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Try putting in a breakpoint and seeing where you blow up. Alternatively you could just check the retain counts of the various items.

Comment: but how to maintain the reference count in xcode 4.2 as I m using it. I dont know what is alternative of retain in xcode 4.2

Comment: You don't need an alternative. You are just missing a retain or doing an extra release somewhere. If you post your code I can take a look at, otherwise I can only offer abstract advice for finding the issue.

Comment: thanks sir I juz go thru the code , and I able to find it , now this problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Actualy problem is as I am using a UIView and on that I am taking a custom view and  on that a table view..so in view did load I was taken a local instances.
so I take it in respective .h, And ***I DID FORWARD DECLARATION*** in viewcontroller class..
(because in that at runtime the instance was released,then that was called so the prob was)

***Note***:-You generally get this error when you send a message to already released instance. So what I suspect in your code is, you created some views and then you added it to some other view and released the previous created view. Now if any action performed on the first view (which is already released) will cause the exception. i.e.: First View contains a button and action for this button's touchup inside is written in FristViewController. Now I created the instance of FirstView and added into second view and released the firstview instance. Now suppose user tap on FirstView's button then, iOS will search for controller (FirstViewController) which is already released, and this problem will occur.